# Store data frame in the form of query

Tags: r, dataframe

`data frame` `D` is `fixed`.

```
> D
   A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1   1  1  1  1  1
2   1  1  2  1  3
3   1  2  1  2  2
4   1  1  2  2  2
5   1  2  2  3  2
6   1  2  2  3  2
7   2  2  1  4  1
8   2  2  1  4  1
9   2  3  1  5  1
10  2  3  2  6  1
```

---

```
> D[D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1 , c("A2", "A3", "A4")]
  A2 A3 A4
4  1  2  2
```

The above query results in a data frame. But instead of storing resulting data frame I want to store the query which results in the above data frame. I want to store the query in such a way so that later on query can be executed easily.

One method is to store the query in the form of string. And later on if execution is required, first we will parse and then execute the query.

Other operations required for stored query

1. add condition of the form `& D$A5==3`
2. add column
3. delete column

Suppose initial query was `D[D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1 , c("A2", "A3", "A4")]`

Add `D$A5==3` to the query

i.e. `D[D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1  & D$A5==3 , c("A2", "A3", "A4")`

Add column `"A5"`

i.e. `D[D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1  & D$A5==3 , c("A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")`

Delete column "A2"

i.e. `D[D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1  & D$A5==3 , c("A3", "A4", "A5")`

Is there any better and efficient way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just write a function?

Comment: @alistaire I was wondering the same

Comment: Probably best to make some sort of query class along with a family of functions for modifying it, similar to how formulas and `update.formula` work.

Comment: Anyway, next time complete the question because now, with further details you provided,  Imy answer seems useless while your first question was a very simple one and tailored for my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build it into a function call:

```
   a12.234 <-function(dat, sub = list(NULL), cols= c("A2", "A3", "A4") ) 
                 subset(dat, 
                        subset = eval(bquote( A1==1 & A2 == 1 & .( if ( 
                           is.null(sub[[1]]) ){TRUE}else{sub} )) ), 
                 select= cols)
> a12.234(D)
  A2 A3 A4
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  1
4  1  2  2
> a12.234(D, sub=quote(A5 == 3) )
  A2 A3 A4
2  1  2  1
```

Adding columns:

```
> a12.234 <-function(dat, sub = list(NULL), add = "") 
      subset(dat, eval(bquote( A1==1 & A2 == 1 & .( if ( 
                                          is.null(sub[[1]]) ){TRUE}else{sub} )) ), 
                 select= c("A2", "A3", "A4", if(add==""){NULL}else{add} ))
> a12.234(D, sub=quote(A5 == 3) )
  A2 A3 A4
2  1  2  1
> a12.234(D, sub=quote(A5 == 3), add="A1" )
  A2 A3 A4 A1
2  1  2  1  1
```

And the final request: deletion from the base vector of column names:

```
a12.234 <-function(dat, sub = list(NULL), add = "", delete=NULL) 
               subset(dat, eval(bquote( A1==1 & A2 == 1 & 
                          .( if ( is.null(sub[[1]]) ){TRUE}else{
                                                      sub} )) ), 
               select= c("A2", "A3", "A4", if(add==""){NULL}else{add} )[
                  if(delete != ""){ -which( c("A2", "A3", "A4") %in% delete)}else{
                                    TRUE}] )
> a12.234( D, delete="A2")
  A3 A4
1  1  1
2  2  1
4  2  2
```

I admit this seems a bit tortured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `expression` to store the query (inside an object of class expression that you can subset etc.) and next execute it with the `eval` function:

```
 query <- expression(D[D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1 , c("A2", "A3", "A4")])

 query
expression(D[D$A1 == 1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 != 1, c("A2", "A3", 
    "A4")])

 eval(query)
  A2 A3 A4
4  1  2  2
```

Comment: suppose query is created as explained by you. Now I want to modify the query by adding `D$A3 = 5`  how can I do it.

Comment: you can do `expr1 <- expression(D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1); expr2 <- expression(D$A3 = 5)` and then `D[eval(expr1) & eval(expr2), c("A2", "A3", "A4")]`

Comment: can't we combine two expressions expr1 and expr2 into 1 i.e. `D$A1==1 & D$A2 == 1 & D$A4 !=1 & D$A3 == 5`